# What's the right punctuation for the following list?

Tags: punctuation, commas, lists, semicolons, periods

> Many cases of animal suicide were discused. A duck drowned
>   itself after the death of its companion. A school of dolphins stranded
>   on a beach with no reason whatsoever. A deer threw itself from a cliff
>   to avoid being eaten by hunting dogs. And the list went on and on.

Should I use comma, semicolon, or just leave it as it is? If I chose the semicolon, where should it start?

Comment: None of the choices are ungrammatical: which sounds best depends on the effect you wish to achieve, and is off-topic here.

Comment: Aside: "discussed" not "discused", and generally "for no reason" rather than "with no reason".

Comment: If you leave these as separate sentences, you might want to consider two issues. 1.) The intransitive usage of `stranded` here is peculiar, but it might be allowed with this meaning (`dolphins stranded`). 2.) Starting the last sentence with a coordinating conjunction (`And the list went on`) is deemed non-standard by many (but not all) references, and as a matter of style probably should be avoided.

Answer (score 7):

Write what sounds natural. I like changing the verbs and joining with commas:

> There were many cases of animal suicide in the paper: a duck drowning
>   itself after the death of its companion, a school of dolphins beaching
>   itself for no apparent reason, a deer throwing itself from a cliff to
>   avoid being eaten by hunting dogs. The list went on and on.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use commas, since each incident listed is in a complete sentence. But you want to group them together to show that it is a list, so semi-colons is the best solution.

*There were many cases of animal suicide in the paper. A duck drowned itself after the death of its companion; a school of dolphins [was] stranded on a beach with no reason whatsoever; a deer threw itself from a cliff to avoid being eaten by hunting dogs. And the list went on and on.*

Answer (score 2):

If you consider the cases as a list you can write:

> Many cases of animal suicide were discussed: a duck drowned itself after the death of its companion, a school of dolphins stranded on a beach with no reason whatsoever, A deer threw itself from a cliff to avoid being eaten by hunting dogs. And the list went on and on.

Answer (score 1):

If the final clause is to be introduced with an 'and', then they should be separated by commas. Whether you place a comma directly before the 'and' ([a usage called the 'serial comma'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma)) is sometimes a matter of style, but in this case I would argue that it is necessary (from intuition, I'm not aware of the terminologies and conventions governing this particular case, although I suspect it's because the overall structure is a bit awkward and this is a sleight-of-hand to cover up the fact). So I would punctuate the sentence thusly:

> There were many cases of animal suicide in the paper. A duck drowned itself after the death of its companion, a school of dolphins stranded on a beach with no reason whatsoever, a deer threw itself from a cliff to avoid being eaten by hunting dogs, and the list went on and on.

Comment: The fact that "the list went on and on" is not actually an item in that list is it? So I wouldn't use "and" there.

Comment: I wouldn't structure it in this way, either, but the OP included an 'and' in his original paragraph. Rather than be presumptuous or prescriptive, I reasoned that he had made up his mind on word choice and simply wanted to know the correct punctuation to separate the component clauses. You could argue that it is a part of the list, anyway, as it serves as a placeholder for the omitted items (akin to '...and so on').

Answer (score 0):

Your current version is fine without any changes, although technically you shouldn't start a sentence with a conjunction so the last sentence you would drop the 'and' (also 'discussed' has two 's's):

> Many cases of animal suicide were discussed. A duck drowned itself
>   after the death of its companion. A school of dolphins stranded on a
>   beach with no reason whatsoever. A deer threw itself from a cliff to
>   avoid being eaten by hunting dogs. The list went on and on.

If you are asking specifically about a semi-colon, you can think of them as a way of putting [two sentences together or replacing a conjunction](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/semicolons_to_extend_a_sentence.htm).

So for your sample it would be:

> Many cases of animal suicide were discussed. A duck drowned itself
>   after the death of its companion. A school of dolphins stranded on a
>   beach with no reason whatsoever. A deer threw itself from a cliff to
>   avoid being eaten by hunting dogs; the list went on and on.

At the risk of it becoming a run-on sentence, you could even do this as it represents a list succinctly:

> Many cases of animal suicide were discussed: a duck drowned itself
>   after the death of its companion, a school of dolphins stranded on a
>   beach with no reason whatsoever, a deer threw itself from a cliff to
>   avoid being eaten by hunting dogs; the list went on and on.

Comment: "technically you shouldn't start a sentence with a conjunction". Why not?

Comment: @msam - That's why it's called a 'conjunction' - it joins two things together. That's also why I said 'technically' because it is very common in English now to do so, so for most people it doesn't 'sound' wrong. If you're writing a conversational piece like a novel, then it is fine but I wouldn't recommend it for technical writing.

Comment: I didn't ask why it's called a conjunction. I asked why you shouldn't start a sentence with it. Try answering my question directly without using a conjunction and without repeating the whole question and you should see my point. "Don't start with a conjunction" is ludicrous advice considering all the literature and daily language that does so.

Comment: @msam - I'm not particularly interested in a flame war over conjunctions, however the 'traditional' view is that conjunctions should not be at the beginning of a sentence. I perfectly accept that within the global reach of English, there are many variations, so in your accepted canon of English feel free to start your sentences with conjunctions.